# Divide a number into weighted parts

Tags: divisibility

Lets say I want to divide 10 into 2 parts where one part should be big; the other should be less than the first part. A split of 6,4 or 7,3 or 8,2 will satisfy this requirement.

Then if I want to split 10 into 3 parts, it could be 5, 3, 2 or 6, 3, 1. Then if I want to split 10 into 4 parts, it could be 4, 3, 2, 1.

Likewise if I want to divide 100 in to 13 parts, how would I do it? Is it possible to define a formula for this kind of splitting?

Note: I am aware that if I try to divide 10 into 10 parts, I get ten 1s. That's okay. If it possible to have weighted splits, excellent; otherwise all good.